# Let $H$ be the base distribution of a Dirichlet process. How is this process well-defined in case $H(B_1) = 0$?

Tags: dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

I have read that the parameters of [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) must be strictly positive.

---

The Dirichlet distribution of order $K \geq 2$ with parameters $\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{K} \color{blue}{> 0}$ has a probability density function with respect to Lebesgue measure on the Euclidean space $\mathbf{R}^{K-1}$ given by
$$
f\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{K} ; \alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{K}\right)=\frac{1}{\mathrm{~B}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})} \prod_{i=1}^{K} x_{i}^{\alpha_{i}-1}
$$
where $\left\{x_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{k=K}$ belong to the standard $(K-1)$-simplex.

---

Then the Dirichlet distribution is then used in the definition of [Dirichlet process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process).

---

Given a measurable set $S$, a base probability distribution $H$ and a positive real number $\alpha$, the Dirichlet process $\mathrm{DP}(H, \alpha)$ is a stochastic process whose sample path (or realization, i.e. an infinite sequence of random variates drawn from the process) is a probability distribution over $S$, such that the following holds. For any measurable finite partition of $S$, denoted $\left\{B_{i}\right\}_{i=1}^{n}$, if $X \sim \operatorname{DP}(H, \alpha)$ then
$$
\left(X\left(B_{1}\right), \ldots, X\left(B_{n}\right)\right) \sim \operatorname{Dir}\left(\alpha H\left(B_{1}\right), \ldots, \alpha H\left(B_{n}\right)\right),
$$
where Dir denotes the Dirichlet distribution and the notation $X \sim D$ means that the random variable $X$ has the distribution $D$.

---

If $H(B_1) = 0$, then $\alpha H(B_1)=0$. How is $\operatorname{Dir}\left(\alpha H\left(B_{1}\right), \ldots, \alpha H\left(B_{n}\right)\right)$ well-defined in this case?

Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Because every realization of this process is a probability distribution on $S,$ its values on sets of measure zero don't matter.  *Ergo,* you may define the process any way you like when $H(B_1)=0.$  Perhaps the visualizations I posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/421266/919 might help with the intuition.

Comment: @whuber Let $X$ be the Dirichlet process in our consideration. When $H(B_1)=0$, $B_1$ is a null set w.r.t. the base measure $H$. Clearly, the probability distribution of $X$ is not $H$. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: I do not follow the logic of your "clearly" or even the intended meaning of the words that follow.  $X$ is a *process* while $H$ is a *base measure:* they cannot be equated or even compared.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the Dirichlet process, as given on the Wikipedia page, is correct only if we use the definition of the Dirichlet distribution as given in [Ferguson, 1973](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-1/issue-2/A-Bayesian-Analysis-of-Some-Nonparametric-Problems/10.1214/aos/1176342360.full). Ferguson's definition is slightly more general than the one on Wikipedia. Under Ferguson's definition, only one of the $\alpha_j$'s need be positive. With this definition, there is no problem with sets of $H$-measure 0.